# Unable to load shared library 'python37' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, tensorflow, keras, python.net

I am quite new to dotnet and Keras.NET, and I was trying to set it up on a goorm.io container. After installing the prerequisites (adding $HOME/.keras/keras.json for Tensorflow backend and pip install numpy), and then adding Keras.NET, I tried to run the XOR sample code, but ran into an error.

```
Unhandled exception. System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'python37' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libpython37: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Py_IsInitialized()
at Python.Runtime.Runtime.Initialize(Boolean initSigs)
at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize(IEnumerable1 args, Boolean setSysArgv, Boolean initSigs) at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize(Boolean setSysArgv, Boolean initSigs) at Python.Runtime.PythonEngine.Initialize() at Numpy.np.InstallAndImport(Boolean force) at Numpy.np.<>c.<.cctor>b__599_0() at System.Lazy1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
at System.Lazy1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor) at System.Lazy1.CreateValue()
at System.Lazy1.get_Value() at Numpy.np.get_self() at Numpy.np.get_float32() at Numpy.DtypeExtensions.GetDtype(Object obj) at Numpy.np.array[T](T[,] object, Dtype dtype, Nullable1 copy, String order, Nullable1 subok, Nullable1 ndmin)
at Proj.Program.Main(String[] args) in /workspace/XOR/Proj/Program.cs:line 14
```

I do not know how to share with the python37 directory. If someone could direct me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated. By the way, I am using Linux if that helps.

Thanks